# Nginx, howto check if there is some extra query arguments (unknow) not included in the permitted argument list

Tags: nginx

I try to get a way to detect any extra query argument not included in the permitted argument list in urls with nginx. The objective is to block any request with any query argument not included in this list.

Correct url: https://www.test.site.com/search?q=test&order=asc

Wrong url: https://www.test.site.com/search?q=test&order=asc&_dflsj=834783423

I managed a site with a huge traffic and there is a lot of abuse from multiple bots. I use microcaching with nginx to protect the site but bot try to use this extra arguments to bypass caching effect.

I have already get the caching to work correctly and mitigate this abuse adding the correct key in the fastcgi_cache_key and not taking in account this "extra" arguments.

But now I want to block them.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression.

For example, if this check is for the `/search` URI only, and the value of `q=` may be any text, and the value for `order=` may be `asc` or `desc`, you could use:

```
location = /search {
    if ($args !~ ^q=[^&]+&order=(asc|desc)$) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

The `!~` operator is a negative match for the regular expression. The remainder of the block contains the necessary statements to process the request.

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

---

Alternatively, use a regular expression in a `map`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example, same check as above, but without having to use an extra `location` block:

```
map $request_uri $reject {
    default                               0;
    ~^/search[?]q=[^&]+&order=(asc|desc)$ 0;
    ~^/search[?]order=(asc|desc)&q=[^&]+$ 0;
    ~^/search$                            1;
}
server {
    if ($reject) { return 403; }
    ...
}
```

Regular expressions are evaluated in order, so the first regular expressions will only match valid URIs, and the last one will reject any `/search` URI that is invalid.

The advantage of `map` is that you can easily add cases, such as other URIs and where the parameters are reversed (as shown in the above example).

Comment: Thanks for you answer but it's more complex than that. Possible urls are the whole site's urls and there is 8 possible valid arguments that can be specified in any order (and maybe more in future), so the "if" and "map" could get really big and difficult to maintain. The ideal approach would be a way to get whole args list, subtract valid ones and if the result is not empty them deny. But I don't know how to do it.